# VLC without border/window decoration in Windows

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to run VLC (2.1, 64 bit) without any chrome on Windows 7.

You can achieve it by going to `Preferences`, and in the `Interface` tab, unchecking `Integrate video in interface`, and also in the `Video` tab, unchecking `Window decorations`.

The problem lies in the fact that without `Window decorations` there is no apparent way to move or resize the video window - in GOM player, for example, you can move window by dragging on the video itself; is there an option for this in VLC?

Ideally, I would like to move the window by the method described above (by dragging the video), and would like the `Window decorations` to reappear on mouseover, to allow resizing; I'm a new VLC user, but unsure how far the customisation goes. - I'd settle with just the moving of the window via dragging the video if this is possible by advanced setting.

There is a [similar question here](https://superuser.com/questions/201667/how-to-disable-all-window-borders-from-the-vlc-playback-window), but not exactly, and no solution to that particular question.

Comment: "without chrome" makes it sound like Chrome browser, you might edit and change that word to border or similar word.

Comment: I blame Google Chrome. But I changed it anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure if you're using all your mouse keys, but I wasn't. You can use AltMove to sign just 1 mouse key and not use a keyboard key at all. I've never used my back key before, just assigned dragging to it and can now freely move the VLC undecorated window around. Just read this 2min ago and already am in love with this. Thank you both so much and hope the key assignement option will work with your wireless mouse as well as it does with mine.

Comment: Thanks @user184245, I switched correct answer as yours works without a keyboard too (though I'm aware it's not super useful for people without superfluous buttons on their mice!)

Answer (score 2):

I am using VLC 2.02. For moving the windows without decorations i am using [AltMove Windows & Mouse Manager](http://www.deskex.com/Altmove/index.asp). (http://www.deskex.com/Altmove/index.asp )
 Hope this helps what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for this. Alt-move pattern is definitely something I found useful on Ubuntu, but it isn't useful in this particular case for me, as I only have a wireless mouse, and like to control everything from my bed :D marked as correct because it works at my desk! :)

Answer (score 0):

An old question! Works for me: Hit F11 in VLC, there is now a border that you can move. Hit F11 again if you wish.