# Video playback as minimalist overlay in corner of screen

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I only have 1 monitor atm. I want to be able to playback video while I use the rest of the monitor to do work. Using the traditional method of windowskeyarrowkey does not leave enough space to work as the monitor is only 1080p native. SO ideally I'd  want something like you see below using vlc player. However I'd want something even better and more minimalist, ideally the removal of the top bar to maximize display space. If there's a method to achieve this for streaming sites like youtube I'd be interested as well.

*ex. VLC*

[image: VLC Example - Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they added always on top and h hotkey to toggle to minimalistic view which does everything u'd want in this respect since the time of posting the OP

Answer (score 2):

> I'd want something even better and more minimalist, ideally the removal of the top bar to maximize display space.

As a comment, I don't believe that removing the title bar increases the video size in any way. That said, you can achieve the removal of the window title bar with some of the [command line options for VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help).

**Borderless**

To remove all the window elements from VLC, you will likely want to use the `--no-video-deco` and `--no-embedded-video` command line options:

```
vlc --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video example.mp4
```

Note that `--no-video-deco` and `--no-embedded-video` will likely only have a noticeable effect when a media source is specified (ex. `example.mp4`).

Be aware that using these options may remove the ability to move the window with click/hold/drag.

---

**Placement**

You can use the `--video-x` and `--video-y` options respectively to specify where you want your playback window to initially appear (starting from the uppermost left corner of the screen):

```
vlc --video-x=100 --video-y=100 --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video example.mp4
```

**Size**

If you want to change the size of the video, you can adjust the `--zoom` factor of the video:

```
vlc --zoom 2 --video-x=100 --video-y=100 --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video example.mp4
```

- `--zoom` can take whole as well as decimal numbers (e.g. `0.25`, `1.5`, `2`, etc.).
- A `--zoom` under one reduces video size and a `--zoom` over one enlarges it.

---

> If there's a method to achieve this for streaming sites like youtube I'd be interested as well.

`example.mp4` is used as a video source above, but this could be e.g. a YouTube URL as well:

```
vlc --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnEMOQTh27s
```

---

**Caveats**

*Windows*

- Using `--no-video-deco` and `--no-embedded-video` with `vlc` will create two VLC windows — a "main" window with all the normal controls and separate borderless "playback" window. You can automatically minimize the "main" window by using the Windows `start` command with VLC i.e.:

  ```
  start "" /min vlc --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video example.mp4
  ```
- Any borderless playback window for a source started from the command line will close automatically once the file is finished.
- The path to `vlc` needs to be in your environment variables to use `vlc` at the command line. Otherwise, you will likely need to specify the full path to `vlc.exe` in your commands.

*Streaming*

One thing to keep in mind about streaming sites in general (and YouTube in particular) is that there are multiple ways to stream data. For instance, the example YouTube link above (`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnEMOQTh27s`) works in VLC. However, the one below (`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o0r9unT4L4`) does not:

```
vlc --no-video-deco --no-embedded-video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o0r9unT4L4
```

In cases like this, you might have to find alternative software such as [mpv](https://mpv.io/) combined with [youtube-dl](http://youtube-dl.org/downloads/) if you really want to watch a given stream.

---

***Sources***

- *[How to disable all window borders from the VLC playback window](https://superuser.com/questions/201667/how-to-disable-all-window-borders-from-the-vlc-playback-window)*
- *[Command Line and resizing with dummy interface](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=125796)*

---

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. In VLC I can make the video window float by checking the option "always on top".
I think this screenshot will help you. [VLC Float on top - example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBMpo.png)